# Как создать объект в Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Я говорю о JS-подобном объекте, т.е. что-то типа
let object = {
first: '1',
second: '2',
third: '3'
};
Никак не получается создать такое в Laravel

Comment: этот "объект" называется json. и примерно половина кода фреймворка Ларавель предназначена для работы с этим форматом.

Comment: Вероятно вы хотите использовать ключи объекта через стрелки... Самый простой способ `$object = (object) ['key' => 'value'];` и теперь вы можете обратиться к нему как `$object->key === 'value'`

Comment: Более сложный для вас через классы, но более правильный с точки зрения разработки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Объект - это экземпляр класса. В Laravel создать экземпляр класса можно например так `$product = new Product();` предварительно заюзав это пространство имён `use App/Models/Product`